# How to resolve Illegal string offset problem in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am a beginner at laravel development. I need to update the dynamic input field value. I tried so many codes but, I am unable to update. I am getting the error "**Illegal string offset 'house_no'**. I have given below using my code

**My Blade File**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>House No</th>
           <th>Street Name</th>
           <th>Area</th>
           <th>Pincode</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($address as $addres)
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{$addres->house_no}}]" value="{{ $addres->house_no}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{$addres->street_name}}]" value="{{ $addres->street_name}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{$addres->area}}]" value="{{ $addres->area}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{$addres->pincode}}]" value="{{ $addres->pincode}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
        <tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Controller File**

```
public function updateUser(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = $request->all();
    
    foreach ($request->settings as $key => $value) {
        Address::update([
            'house_no' => $value['house_no'],
            'street_name' => $value['street_name'],
            'area' => $value['area'],
            'pincode' => $value['pincode'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: please put more sample source related to your problem

Comment: that's not how you access the values :/

Comment: `$value` in your loop is a string ... your array `$request->settings` has only one dimension

Comment: see here for retrieve input data https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: How can I achive this?

Comment: could you help me with my code level?

Comment: @Karthika see my answer , i share example sample code. I hope this one helps to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add an index to the array inputs you are creating where the key for the element is the `id` of the record (`settings[key][attribute]`). At the moment you have a single dimensional array that on the backside would end up only being 1 set of attributes for an address.

Assuming `$addresses` is an Eloquent Collection of models:

```
@foreach ($addresses as $key => $address)
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{ $key }}][house_no]" value="{{ $address->house_no}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{ $key }}][street_name]" value="{{ $address->street_name}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{ $key }}][area]" value="{{ $address->area}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="settings[{{ $key }}][pincode]" value="{{ $address->pincode}}"  class="form-control" /></td>
<tr>
@endforeach
```

Then your loop on the backside could iterate the 'sets' of settings:

```
foreach ($request->input('settings', []) as $key => $value) {
    Address::whereKey($key)->update(
        'house_no' => $value['house_no'],
        'street_name' => $value['street_name'],
        'area' => $value['area'],
        'pincode' => $value['pincode'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have used this code now am getting error Undefined index: house_no

Comment: @Karthika sorry, that was my error ... updated the names of the keys in the form inputs